# JNI: Connecting Java with modules in other programming languages

Tags: java, php, python, ruby, node.js

If I have a Java backend, and I have multiple web tier applications written in non-JVM languages like PHP, Python, Perl, Ruby, Node.js, etc, and if I want to get Java and non-JVM pieces connected, can I use JNI to bind them together? I understand that there are REST/SOAP web service options, but if I use JNI to directly connect Java and non-JVM pieces, is it more direct and efficient than using web services? Is there an easy and universal way to use JNI to connect Java and all other non-JVM languages?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about easy and universal. In addition to JNI, there is

1. [Simplified Wrapper and Interface Generator](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html)
2. [Java Native Access](https://github.com/twall/jna)
3. [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-c-clients.html)
4. [Apache Camel](http://codebrane.com/blog/2009/07/28/talking-stomp-to-apache-camel-with-c/)

But I'd really look at SWIG (e.g. Number 1 above) if I were you.

You may also want to look at the [Apache Commons Bean Scripting Framework](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bsf//faq.html).
Finally, all of your listed languages have JVM hostable counterparts. For example, [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino) and [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) and [Jython](http://jython.org/) and [jRuby](http://www.jruby.org/) and [jerl](https://code.google.com/p/jerl/) and [sisc](http://sisc-scheme.org/).

Comment: Thanks Elliott. How is the interoperability of SWIG between Java and all non-JVM languages' native engines like C-Python interpreter? Can I call Python/PHP/Node functions directly from Java and vice versa?

Comment: @tonga There are multiple ways to do all of this. I need something more specific than is it possible? The answer is almost certainly yes.

Comment: If I don't want to use JVM counterparts of these languages like Jython/JRuby, then SWIG is probably the best way to go if I want to call other languages via JNI? My supposed scenario is some web tier front end written by Django/Rails/Node etc. and I want to use Java backend to talk to them to connect to the persistent layer.

Comment: Java Native Access or SWIG (I think), but don't forget options 3 and 4.